# Most transactions in a block

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, block, transaction-weight, block-weight

Block [689074](https://mempool.space/block/000000000000000000033c9d18636bdfbaa96d435f4684d8b6efefdc3f826763) had 4,463 transactions.

1. Is this the highest number of transactions in a block until now?
2. What are the things that affect the number of transactions possible in a block?

Few observations based on comparison of two blocks: [666666](https://btc.bitaps.com/666666)(left) and [689074](https://btc.bitaps.com/000000000000000000033c9d18636bdfbaa96d435f4684d8b6efefdc3f826763)(right)

Size of transactions:

[image: size-of-tx]

Type of transactions:

[image: segwit-percent]

Outputs:

[image: outputs]

Comment: It is a bit confusing that you appear to give the labels for the examples in the reverse order as the images that follow, perhaps you could edit them to have the same order or label the images explicitly. Also FYI, the source of the images seems to have some bugs, since the virtualsize of blocks cannot be greater than 1MvB.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the labels. Checking virtual size bug and reading more about 1MvB limit.

Comment: Well, more accurately, the blockweight limit is 4,000,000 weight units, which corresponds to 1,000,000 vbytes. I see three other explorers stating that the block had a weight of 3,993,107 WU (998,277 vB), which matches what my node says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the highest number of transactions in a block until now?

The highest number of transactions in a block is 12239 in block 00000000000000001080e6de32add416cd6cda29f35ec9bce694fea4b964c7be at height 367853.

> What are the things that affect the number of transactions possible in a block?

Besides the block size/weight limit, the primary thing that affects how many transactions can fit in a block is the size of the transactions themselves.

When a transaction is added, it takes up space that other transactions could make use of. So the smaller a transaction is, the more transactions can be included in a block. If we look at the winning block, we see that the transactions in it tend to be very small, measuring 81 (v)bytes on average, compared to the 2-300 vbytes in the blocks that you mentioned.